# Expected value of joint quantile functions

Tags: independence, quantiles

Consider a population of individuals (not a sample). We are interested in two variables, $X$ and $Y$, which are independent. $X$ distributed with pdf $f(x)$ and CDF $F(x)$, and $Y$ distributed with pdf $g(y)$ and CDF $G(y)$.

Consider the quantile funtions of these two distributions. **Importantly, the support of these two functions is the same, because the variables belong to the same population**. Thus, we have:
$$ x(i) = Q_x(i) =  F^{-1}(i) \qquad y(i) = Q_y(i) = G^{-1}(i) \tag{1}\label{1}
$$
(You can think of this set up in the alternative way. Assign a continuous index $i \in [0,1]$ to every person in the (infinite) population such that their values of $X$ and $Y$ correspond to the quantile functions above.)

Now, I have the following term:
$$ \int_0^1 x(i)  y(i) \; \text{d}i \tag{2}\label{2}
$$
Since the integral of the quantile function over the whole support is equal to the mean (see [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/164788/expected-value-as-a-function-of-quantiles#164790)), I get the idea that somehow the above term is equivalent to
$$ \int_0^1 x(i) \ \text{d}i \int_0^1 y(i) \ \text{d}i  \tag{3}\label{3}
$$
which is equivalent to the multiplication of the means.

In other words, **I am looking for the equivalent of $$E(XY)=E(X)E(Y) \tag{4}\label{4}$$ using quantile functions.**

Below is how far I've got. Let's start from the definition of expected value for independent random variables:
$$ \int_X \int_Y xy \; f(x) g(y) \; \text{d}x \; \text{d} y = E(X) \; E(Y)  \tag{5}\label{5}
$$ 
Now, implicit differentiation means that:
$$ \text{d}i = \frac{\partial F(x)}{\partial x} \text{d}x = f(x) \text{d}x\qquad \text{d}i = \frac{\partial G(y)}{\partial y} \text{d}y = g(y) \text{d}y  \tag{6}\label{6}
$$
Replacing these above we get to:
$$ \int_0^1 \int_0^1 x(i) y(i) \; \text{d}i \; \text{d} i = E(X) \; E(Y)  \tag{7}\label{7}
$$ 
Here I'm stuck. Any ideas how to proceed (if it is actually possible?)

Comment: Please pause to consider simple cases.  For instance, suppose your population $\Omega$ contains a subset $E$ with a probability $p$ strictly between $0$ and $1.$ Define $Y$ to be the indicator of $E$ and $X=-Y.$ Thus, $F_X$ and $F_Y$ are piecewise constant; $F_X(x)$ jumps by $p$ at $-1$ and $1-p$ at $0,$ whereas $F_Y$ jumps by $1-p$ at $0$ and by $p$ at $1.$ As you may compute, $x(i)y(i)=0$ everywhere but the integrals of $x$ and $y$ are both nonzero.

Comment: @whuber But X is not independent of Y. Their correlation is -1.

Comment: Yes--but it is easy to construct independent variables with these two CDFs, whence the problem remains: what you are attempting to show obviously is not true.

Comment: @whuber Well, if you can provide a counterexample, or show where the proof went wrong, that will be a good answer.

Comment: You haven't a proof at all: you are invoking relationships among integrals that are not generally true.  You will find that out by attempting to justify the manipulations you make: can you quote a property or theorem to support each one?

Comment: @whuber you mean the first step in the answer is unwarranted?

Comment: Your first step appears to replace the density functions by the quantile functions.  
  (It's hard to tell for sure, because the expression you obtain makes no sense.)  That has no justification at all.

Comment: @whuber As far as I understand, I'm doing the same that [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/164788/expected-value-as-a-function-of-quantiles#164790) does.

Comment: No, you are not: somehow you mysteriously turn a single integral into a double integral.

Answer (score 0):

Quite noob indeed. Notice that:

$$ \int_0^1 \int_0^1 x(i) y(i) \ \text{d}i \ \text{d} i = E(X) \ E(Y)$$

is also

$$ \int_0^1 \left( \int_0^1 x(i) y(i) \ \text{d}i \right) \text{d} i = E(X) \ E(Y)$$

But the term inside the parenthesis, whatever it is, does not depend on $i$. Denote it as $C$, then:

$$ \int_0^1 C \ \text{d} i = E(X) \ E(Y)$$

Solving the integral, we get:

$$ \int_0^1 C \ \text{d} i = C i \Big|^1_0 = C = E(X) \ E(Y)$$

This is,

$$ \int_0^1 x(i) y(i) \ \text{d}i = E(X) \ E(Y)$$

Comment: Please study my comment to your question.  Your mathematical notation here, which has two "$\mathrm{d}i$" in the integral, makes no sense and may be leading you astray.

Answer (score 0):

If the integrand $f(x,y)$ can be partitioned into a product of functions of the individual differentials $$f(x,y) = g(x) h(y)$$  then we can write a double integral as a product of single integrals.

$$ \int_{a}^{b}\int_{c}^{d} g(x) h(y) dx dy = \left(\int_{c}^{d} g(x) dx\right)\left(\int_{a}^{b}  h(y) dy\right)$$

> Now, I have the following term:
> $$ \int_0^1 x(i)  y(i) \; \text{d}i 
> $$

This makes little sense, but possibly you meant to write

$$ \int_0^1 \int_0^1 x(p_1)  y(p_2) \; \text{d}p_1\text{d}p_2
$$