# Calculating expected value from quantiles

Tags: expected-value, quantiles, cumulative-distribution-function

For probabilities $p_i=\frac{i}{10}$ where $i=1, \dots, 10$, the respective quantiles are $\tau_i$. How can I calculate an approximate expected value?

Comment: If you had quartiles you could do https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trimean, I guess something similar could be done with deciles.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using my answer at [Expected value as a function of quantiles?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/164788/expected-value-as-a-function-of-quantiles/164790#164790), a general expression for the expectation in terms of the quantile function is
$$  \mu=\int_0^1 Q(p)\; dp
$$   in the continuous case, and that answer extends to the general case.

Looking at the approximating sums defining the integral, you can read this as *the mean is the mean of the quantiles*, which gives an approximation for your case as
$$ \frac{\sum_1^{10} \tau_i}{10}
$$

Comment: Isn't that slightly biased upwards due there being no $Q(0)$ and if yes, do you see a way of correcting that?

Comment: @LukasLohse: Yes, but this comes from the biased definition of $p_i$ by the OP

Comment: @LukasLohse Use the i's from 1 to 9?

Comment: @LukasLohse: I guess this must be adapted to the specific def of quantile used ... it doesn't seem right to leave out the top quantile completely

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen In the case where random quantiles are available, do we use the same approach?

Comment: @user529295: What do you mean by random quantiles?

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen, for $p_1 = \frac{1}{10}, p_2 = \frac{1}{7}, \dots, p_N=1$, where N is the number of quantiles.

Comment: @user529295: I will augment tomorrow

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen Rechecking with you on this